# filepicker-rails w/signup form: button to `remove` the file in Filepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, api, filepicker.io

In my Rails 3.2 app I am using Filepicker through the `filepicker-rails` gem to allow users to upload a profile photo on the signup form. In the `f.filepicker_field` I am using the `onchange` option to call an `onImageUpload()` function that gets information about the newly uploaded image from the automatically-generated `event.fpfile` and disables the Filepicker browse button:

```
function onImageUpload() {
  file = event.fpfile
  img = $("<img>").prop("src", file.url).css({
      width: '160px',
      height: '160px',
    });
  $("#profile_photo_preview").append(img);
  $(".filepicker-button").toggleClass("disabled");
};
```

I read about the `event.fpfile` at the Filepicker docs [section on Widgets](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#widgets). In the form I also have a link that, when clicked, removes the recently updated image from the DOM and re-enables the Filepicker button:

```
:javascript 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#picture-remover").click(function() {
      $("#profile_photo_preview").html("");
      if ( $(".filepicker-button").hasClass("disabled") ) {
        $(".filepicker-button").toggleClass("disabled");
      };
    });
  });
...
...
= link_to "Remove Picture", id: "picture-remover"
```

This all seems to work pretty well. The only problem is that if a user removes the first picture and then uses the Filepicker browser to upload another, the original picture is still being saved in my Filepicker account.

I'd like to have my "Remove Picture" link remove the picture not only from the DOM, but also from my Filepicker account altogether. The Filepicker docs have a section on removing/deleting files [here](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#remove) but I don't really understand the example code or how to implement it for myself. I'm particularly confused about the relationship between the `InkBlob` that is mentioned for removing a file and the `event.fpfile` object that I'm using to display a thumbnail preview.

So far I've tried adding the following line to my "Remove Picture" link but nothing happens:

```
:javascript 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#picture-remover").click(function() {
      $("#profile_photo_preview").html("");
      if ( $(".filepicker-button").hasClass("disabled") ) {
        $(".filepicker-button").toggleClass("disabled");
      };
      filepicker.remove(InkBlob); #added this line
    });
  });
```

Many thanks to anyone who can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

InkBlob and event.fpfile objects have the same role and the same attributes.

In your example you can pass event.fpfile object to remove function.

```
var file = event.fpfile;
filepicker.remove(
  file,
  function(){
    console.log("Removed");
  }
);
```

Generally to remove filepicker file you only need it's url.

So this code also works fine:

```
var someObject = {url: 'https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/xaXphhT9R0GB1tPYUQAr'};
filepicker.remove(
  someObject,
  function(){
    console.log("Removed");
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for letting this sit for so long. This makes sense but (for the second snippet you provided) how do I get access to that url dynamically while the user is adding/removing  the photo?